# How to list all the goals of a particular maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How to list all the goals of a particular maven plugin (e.g. I would like to list all the goals for maven-clean-plugin or maven-javadoc-plugin, how do I do that?)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command to list all goals of a particular maven plugin.

```
mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins 
                  -DartifactId=maven-war-plugin             
                  -Ddetail=true`
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always look here [in the documentation?](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/plugin-info.html)

Comment: I would like to avoid exactly that, it takes more time to look at documentation for various plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

on linux you could use the bash_completion plugins that are out there for maven.  this has been working for me:
https://github.com/juven/maven-bash-completion